# Liking JQuery to anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have an anchor tag which when clicked should 'popup' a div that is hidden

```
<a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink">read more</a>
when read more is clicked, just below it this div should show, 
<div id="myAnchor" name="d-content">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <ul>
                    <li>item one</li>
                    <li>item two</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
        </div>
I have a JQuery code that isn't working as expected,
    <script>
  $('#anchor1').click(function(){
    $('#myAnchor').show();
});
</script>
```

how can I display the hidden div successfully?

Comment: try this inside your click `$($(this).attr("href")).show();`

Comment: to show the hidden div, you first need to hide it :) . either use `hide()` before the click function, either use `display:none` in css . Second, you have an `href` attribute linking it to the id of the div . Why not use that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `href` value by using `$(this).attr("href")` since `href` is an `attribute`.

```js
$('#anchor1').click(function() {
  $($(this).attr("href")).show();
});
```

```css
#myAnchor {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink">read more</a> 
<div id="myAnchor" name="d-content">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <ul>
      <li>item one</li>
      <li>item two</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```js
$('#anchor1').click(function() {
  $('#myAnchor').show();
});
```

```css
#myAnchor{
  display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink">read more</a> when read more is clicked, just below it this div should show,
<div id="myAnchor" name="d-content">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <ul>
      <li>item one</li>
      <li>item two</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```